# How to call a javascript file in another javascript file React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, frontend

I have two React projects, one is Home page and the other one is Date range. Now i want to merge two react project into one. I copied file from one project and pasted into another project. Now how can I call those js function in another js file?

POSTLIST.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
class PostList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/last15days").then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        posts: response.data,
      });
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>get call in React js</h1>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div key={post.id}>{post.id} </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default PostList;
```

ABOUT.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <!-- banner --> */}
        <section class="inner-page-banner" id="home"></section>
        {/* <!-- //banner -->
    <!-- page details --> */}
        <div class="breadcrumb-agile">
          <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
              About Us
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
        {/* <!-- //page details -->
        <!--about-mid --> */}
        <section class="banner-bottom py-5" id="exp">
          <div class="container py-md-5">
            <h3 class="heading text-center mb-3 mb-sm-5">About More</h3>
            <div class="row mid-grids mt-lg-5 mt-3">
              <div class="col-md-5 content-w3pvt-img">
                <img src="assets/image/ban1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
              </div>
              <h1>TODO : DATERANGE</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default About;
```

Now i want to call Postlist.js in About.js How to call that function

Comment: At top of ABOUT.js you can 
import PostList from "pathtopostlist";
And then in render method you can render it:
<PostList />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't call these *projects*. Basically, you wanna have two *components* of React into one project. In the end of your files, you are *export*ing your components. This way, you can *import* that into the main component and call that function. The way you are exporting is the *default* way, meaning that the export isn't *named*, i.e., you can import the file in the following syntax:

About.js

```js
import PostList from './PostList.js';
// use <PostList /> anywhere in your code now
// ...
```

Comment: Import PostList is fine and works well but i expect to call PostList in TODO portion how can i do that

Comment: Wherever you need to call it, just call it like `<PostList />` in your render method of course.

Comment: You can call it like `<div><h1>TODO : DATERANAGE</h1><PostList /></div>`

Answer (score 0):

assuming both the files are on the same hierarchy. you need to import POSTLIST.js in ABOUT.js

```
import PostList from './POSTLIST'
```

Comment: `/div>
<h1>TODO : DATERANGE</h1> 
//  i expect call PostList function Here
 </div>`

Comment: @Raghav If you imported already in the file then add `<PostList />` wherever you want to call it.